# Cambiar comas por espacios en php

Tags: php

Soy nuevo en PHP, utilizo un codigo que encontre, pero honestamente no lo entiendo del todo. Lo que hace es traducir una palabra por otra. Es decir, tengo una tabla en la base de datos que divide una palabra en varios idiomas.

Mi problema es que cuando coloco una palabra en el textarea del otro lado salen divididas por coma. Ejemplo: coloco "hello hello" y el resultado es "hello,hello"

Copiare el codigo completo y luego dire donde esta la parte que creo que causa ese error:

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","USER","PASS","DB");
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

$active1=$_POST['active1'];
$active2=$_POST['active2'];
$texare=$_POST['texare'];
$result=["tran"=>array(),"icosuc"=>"","sugwor"=>array(),"suglan"=>""];
$issuccess=false;

$sp = '/ /';
$setofwords=preg_split($sp,$texare);

$AllWordsOfLanguageActive1=array();


$sql="SELECT ".$active1."  AS active1  , ".$active2."  AS active2 FROM content";
$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

    if(!empty($texare)){
        foreach($setofwords as $word) {
            array_push($AllWordsOfLanguageActive1,$r["active1"]);
            foreach($AllWordsOfLanguageActive1 as $woract1){
                if(strpos($woract1,$word) != false ){
                    array_push($result["sugwor"],"<li>".$woract1."</li>");
                }
            }
            if($r["active1"] == $word){
                array_push($result["tran"],$r["active2"]);
                $issuccess=true;
            }
        }
    }
}

$sql2="SELECT * FROM content";
$query2=mysqli_query($con,$sql2);

while($r2=mysqli_fetch_array($query2)){

    $languages=["anglais","francais","arabe","espagnol","italian","hindi", "russ"];

    foreach($languages as $lan){
        if((preg_match("/{$r2[$lan]}/i",$texare)) && ($lan!=$active1)){
            $result["suglan"]=$lan;
        }
    }
}

if($issuccess==true){
    $result["icosuc"]="<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign'></span>";
    $result["sugwor"]=array();
}

echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

Creo que el problema esta en esta seccion del codigo:

```
if($r["active1"] == $word){
                    array_push($result["tran"],$r["active2"]);
                    $issuccess=true;
                }
```